# How to play raw audio in Iphone? (using ffmpeg)

Tags: iphone, stream, ffmpeg, avaudioplayer, mms

I am a student who is trying to make mms stream audio app.
I got mms stream using libmms, and decoded wma audio using ffmpeg.
But however I don't know What to do next.

I recently saw similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112650/using-ffmpeg-audio-conversion-in-the-iphone) in stackoverflow site. (Writer is **c4r1o5**)
But He used cfwritestreamwrite after avcodec_decode_audio2.
Is that right? I think It is not necessary because network problem finished after mms_connect, ffmpeg decode.

Is that necessary to use?
I tried to put raw audio to audio buffer. and when play, It only comes with white noise.

Please help me.
Any hint or comment would be vey appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Is it mandatory to use ffmpeg? There are other ways to do this using AVFoundation and/or CoreAudio

Comment: Another way to decode wma audio in Iphone? I have not seen for

Comment: You are right, wma can't be decoded those frameworks. I misread the question.

Comment: hi i am doing a similar project. How did you manage to decode the wma stream from libmms using ffmpeg? can you post some sample codes to help me get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post necessary code.
And, You don't necessarily use CFWriteStreamWrite.
Even though I have no experience with CFWriteStreamWrite, It is not necessary in mms streaming.
All you need is to Connect MMS, Decode wma audio file, Queue audio buffer to play in iphone.
I think you have to know about iphone [Audio Queue Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005117)
And be sure to use thread when get audio frame.
Basic information lies that site.

Finally, the reason only comes with white noise is because you set wrong mAudioData.
Use `memcpy` to copy audio memory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the AudioQueueOutputCallback to pass the decoded audio data to AudioQueue.

```
- (void)handlePlayCallback:(AudioQueueRef) inAudioQueue buffer:(AudioQueueBufferRef) inBuffer {
    // copy decoded audio data to inBuffer->mAudioData
    // and set the size of the copied data like this
    // inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize = data_written

    if(inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize > 0) {
        AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAudioQueue, inBuffer, 0, NULL);
    }
}
```